# Google Chrome redirects to network provider’s page

Tags: google-chrome

Few days ago I tried to connect to internet in a public library. There you have to connect through wireless. After that you can only acces the provider page, and then you have to authenticate to gain access to internet. I completed all those steps and now, every time I try to open google.com, I’m redirected to that network provider’s page. (Google.com is my default web page.) So I don’t know how to reset that. It happens when I type google.com by hand or I use the bookmark.

Anyone has any idea how to solve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your keywords there were "public library". They are just issuing you a homepage redirection and I believe it's sticking once you change wireless networks? If so just DNS flush.

[What does DNS flushing do?](https://superuser.com/questions/235749/what-does-dns-flushing-do)